# How to add a splash view that looks like a UIAlert

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, splash-screen

I need a view with functionality of a splash.
But I don't need at the beginning of app load.
I need this during user asynchronous request processing.

The look of it should be like a small alert box, but again, I want my customization here:
I do not want it to look like any other `UIAlertview`.
I do not want any buttons (OK/cancel) on it, since it is to be discarded when app wants it. User should not discard it.

I am confused between two approaches: 
Should I use `UIViewController` (but want to make it look like a modal box, and also of alert size, not 320 X 480)?
Or should I use customized `UIAlertView` without buttons? I doubt if I get freedom to play with it much.

Comment: you mean you just want to pupulate the uiview with anything you want and that uiview to pop up like uialert view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think people are way too focused on the alert view part of your question.  You don't need to base this off an alert view.  Use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Comment: Thanks for a very direct answer to what I need. Maybe there aren't enough questions (properly phrased) on stackoverflow to address this need, that's why I wasn't clear from beginning? If it wasn't so, I would rephrase my question.

Comment: One quick thing I realize is - the present set of examples do not serve my purpose. They all use showWhileExecuting that wants me to define my background task. But this task is async. It returns immediately, but I want MBProgressHUD till its delegate returns, not the background task. Hope you get my problem? I am stuck, please help!

Comment: Look at the URL example, it handles an async task.

Comment: Question is: will it stop when the function returns, or will it stop when the delegate is called that will signal that it is finished? I want the later.

Comment: Yes, I know.  Look at the example.  It does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom `UIAlertView`.

You can read this tutorial: http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2009/04/23/subclass-uialertview-to-create-a-custom-alert/

The tutorial shows how to create a custom `UIAlertView` without buttons

Comment: Thanks! I already went through it, but it wasn't quite clear at first to me, so I posted here. It was all worth the effort, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use UIAlertView without any buttons!

```
splashAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data is Loading" 
                                             message:@"Please wait until data will finish loading" 
                                            delegate:self 
                                   cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

[splashAlertView show];
[splashAlertView addSubview:yourSplashSubview];
```

And then, when your data will finish loading just call:

```
[splashAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:0];
[splashAlertView release];
splashAlertView = NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for the simplistic approach, I think I will give it a try besides MBProgressHUD just to see if I can tweak it the way I want. This will give me some exercise, if at all, above and beyond my deadline allows :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just use a UIView subclass. You can style the UIView like you want and whenever you need to show the "alert", create an instance of the view and add it to the current visible view.

Disable interactions on the current visible view till this UIView is visible. And when you remove it from the top-most view, enable interactions again.

Comment: Thanks for the approach, however I was looking for something more concrete, priorly done, with some kind of example code that will help me rush in with my deadlines :-) I believe MBProgressHUD addresses what I need really.

Comment: Yup, that uses a UIView as well.